# illegal string offset when trying to get array value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just trying to get the max value of a row in my table, I then want to insert that value into another table, so I'm trying to get that max value, and every time I'm trying to do something with it, I get this error "illegal string offset" .

```
$qry2= "SELECT MAX(buss_id) FROM businesses";
$result= mysqli_query($con,$qry2);
$maxid = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result);

print_r ($maxid);
foreach($maxid as $individual_data)
{
   //Assign the values
   $maxx = $individual_data['buss_id'];
}
```

My `print_r` function prints everything properly, but I just can't access the value I need to manipulate. I'm a beginner, please be kind. Thank you.
`Array ( [MAX(buss_id)] => 47 )`

Comment: The array key will be the column name.  In this case the column name is `MAX(buss_id)` so either you need to change your query to `SELECT MAX(buss_id) AS buss_id` or change your code to get the key as `$maxx = $individual_data['MAX(buss_id)'];`

Comment: @GordonM
 Illegal string offset 'MAX(max_buss_id)'
mith's answer worked, though. Thank you man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `alias`

```
$qry2= "SELECT MAX(buss_id) AS maxid FROM businesses";
$result= mysqli_query($con,$qry2);
$maxid = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result);

echo $maxid['maxid'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Youn should use a proper alias  for assign the name  that you use for accessing  eg:

```
 $qry2= "SELECT MAX(buss_id) as buss_id FROM businesses";
```

Comment: @Mar1ak   . well if my answer  is useful  (like others ) you could rate properly ... over 15  you can use upper  arrow left to answer  for sign as useful

Answer (score 1):

Since your query is `SELECT MAX(buss_id) FROM businesses`, the resulting column name will be `MAX(buss_id)` as is evident the the `print_r` result you have shared.

```
Array ( [MAX(buss_id)] => 47 )
```

You will have to `alias` the resulting field name as you want to get it:

```
$qry2   = "SELECT MAX(buss_id) AS max_buss_id FROM businesses";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$qry2);
$maxid  = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result);

foreach ($maxid as $individual_data)
{
    //Assign the values
    $maxx = $individual_data['max_buss_id'];
}
```

Comment: This still gave me the same error. mith's answer worked, though. Your suggestion would work if  $individual_data['max_buss_id']; became 
$maxid['max_buss_id']; 
I really don't understand it, since $individual_data should be the same as $maxid in the foreach loop. But having $individual_data['max_buss_id'] doesn't work and $maxid['max_buss_id']  works. Thanks for answering!

Comment: @Mar1ak Did u noticed the `AS max_buss_id` in the SQL query? You might have missed it I think.

Comment: @Jmoos Yes bro I did. Also I just edited my first comment, I meant to say 
mith's answer. 
You all suggested the same thing, which is correct but for some reason using the foreach's $key variable AKA $individual_data in my case doesn't work. It's no big deal however. I don't need to foreach anything, I was just trying to assign the value to some variable using foreach. It was already achieved in Mith's answer without the use of foreach. I pointed it out cause it's just weird.

Comment: @Mar1ak Hmm. What else is causing the problem then? Anyway, good to know that smith's answer worked and you got it solved :)

Comment: @Jmoos I wish I knew. As far as I understand it. The $individual_data should be the same as the $maxid in the foreach loop. Apparently it's not quite like that. Otherwise it should've worked just like you suggested. Luckily I won't need a foreach loop for my code. Thanks a lot man =)

Answer (score -1):

> @Mar1ak you did only one mistake, change $individual_data['buss_id'] to
>   $individual_data['max'] because in your query you use max() without any
>   alias so max() will return value with column name max

```
$qry2= "SELECT MAX(buss_id) FROM businesses";
    $result= mysqli_query($con,$qry2);
    $maxid = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result);

print_r ($maxid);
foreach($maxid as $individual_data)
{
   //Assign the values
   $maxx = $individual_data['max'];}
```

Comment: That still won't work.  The array key name is wrong.

Comment: what you are getting in your array print_r ($maxid); ? update your question with this